How to generate a skeleton (medial axis) of a polygon using Fortune's algorithm?
I have been learning recently about Fortune's algorithm to generate the Voronoi diagram given some input but I was interested in the application of this within polygons to generate skeletons (also known as the polygon's medial axis) but I can't seem to find anything when searching.
I am sure this is a solved problem because I was reading this tutorial and it mentioned this problem in the "Computational morphology and shape analysis" part in the 2nd page (and also included a picture of it, Fig2.b) but I can't find anything to read up on it. Are there any accessible (i.e., readable by CompGeom beginners) papers out there that tackle this problem?

This isn't quite the answer you were asking, but related paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00009429

How to generate a skeleton via Fortune's algorithm
The book Computational Geometry by de Berg et al. discusses Voronoi diagrams and Fortune's algorithm in Chapter 7. Section 7.3 discusses how to extend Fortune's algorithm to sites that are disjoint line segments. This is a fairly standard extension, and can be found in other places as well.
Now, in principle, if you start with a polygon with non-crossing vertices, you could shorten the segments (perhaps symbolically) to make them disjoint. The set of bisectors of the Voronoi diagram then contains the medial axis, which you can extract after removing the bisectors on reflex vertices of the polygon.
Why you shouldn't
In practice, this is not so simple. Implementing line sweep algorithms can already be quite a challenge on its own, but ensuring the "shorten" step works properly is also non-trivial. Indeed, the paper Finding the Medial Axis of a Simple Polygon in Linear Time by Chin et al. notes

[...] Voronoi diagram algorithms for line segments can also be used, although
implementing a general algorithm to handle the degenerate cases of segments with the
same endpoints is a headache.

The paper VRONI: An engineering approach to the reliable and efficient
computation of Voronoi diagrams of points and line segments by Martin Held discusses the challenges involved in implementing such an algorithm. The paper does not use Fortune's algorithm, but the challenges in the paper are encountered with other algorithms to compute the Voronoi diagram as well.
I suspect that the reason you are not finding material on how to apply Fortune's algorithm to obtain a medial axis, is that this approach is inferior to other existing approaches, both in theory (Fortune's algorithm is $O(n\log n)$, while there is a linear time algorithm) and in practice (the edge cases involved with using a Voronoi diagram are difficult to implement).

That's an interesting take but I would like to note that I am not interested in disjoint line segments but rather I am interested in polygons exclusively. Disjoint line segments don't exist in my problem. To me it feels like it would just be the standard Fortune's Algorithm + restricting the generated VD to only within the space of the polygon but I was hoping for an elegant solution. Other than the polygon's edges themselves, there would only be points.
Would you say that your answer still applies?
Also, the paper says "simple polygons", by that does it mean that it's not self-intersecting?

To obtain a medial axis of a polygon, the edges of the polygon need to be sites of the VD. So the Fortune's algorithm needs to be extended to allow for line segments as sites. (this among others means that the VD can contain parabolic arcs) If we simplify the problem by making the line segments disjoint, extending Fortune's algorithm is doable. It is not difficult to see that this algorithm can be extended further to line segments that do not intersect in their interior, but it is difficult to actually do it.

As for the paper, a simple polygon does not self-intersect and has no holes.
